How to handle unexpected errors thrown inside an async function?
Let's say there's an async function that has an implementation bug, for example:
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(undefined_variable);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

How can I call this function and handle the ReferenceError it will throw?
I've tried using a .catch block as follows:
resolveAfter2Seconds().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log(error));

And also a wrapper function like so:
async function safeAsyncCall() {
    try {
        return await resolveAfter2Seconds()
    } catch {
        console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
}

safeAsyncCall().then(result => console.log(result))

Neither of which work (the code still crashes with a ReferenceError).
How can I safely call this function?

Do you have access to the source code of resolveAfter2Seconds?

For the sake of this question, the source code can be viewed but not changed

So that means that resolveAfter2Seconds is defined in an external file or library that you have to use and because of that you cannot change it?

Yep, that's the case here

the upshot is, resolveAfter2Seconds is poorly written

You cannot safely call this function, it's broken. It throws an exception asynchronously, and there's nothing you can do about that. You need to fix the code, e.g. by writing function resolveAfter2Seconds() { return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 2000); }).then(() => undefined_variable); } or async function resolveAfter2Seconds() { await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 2000); }); return undefined_variable; }. In both those cases, the function returns a promise that it will reject when the error happens. Never write non-promise asynchronous code that throws!

I know that this isn't what you want to hear, but I don't think there's any safe way to call that function. It's just broken code.
You can work around it like KLASANGUI suggested in his answer but I personally would rather fix it.
If this library is installed via npm, i.e in your node_modules, I would edit it from within node_modules and use patch-package or yarn patch. This will generate a patch file from your changes which can then be applied each time npm install is run using something like postinstall.
As someone who's dealt with a lot of broken js packages, this is what I would do. I don't like having to do weird hacks in my own code because of someone else's broken code.

The answer to the Original Poster question depends on the environment where the code will be running and if the script is a ESModule or CommonJS.
In browsers, for example, you can just listen to unhandled errors like this:
window.addEventListener
(
   'error', error =>
   {
      // Handle unhandled errors here...
   }
);


Window: error event -
The error event is fired on a Window object when a resource failed to load or couldn't be used — for example if a script has an execution error.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event
Note that in your code, if running at a browser, will only throw an error in ESModule mode because if in CommonJS mode it tries to retrieve the variable as a property of window, which should return undefined (in most cases).
In NodeJs, you can like this:
process.on
(
   'uncaughtException', error =>
   {
      // Handle unhandled errors here...
   }
})

Each environment should have it's own way of doing this...
EDIT 1:
Example for OP specific node/express environment:
const eventEmmiter = new ( await import('events') ).EventEmitter;

app.get('/some/route', function SomeRoute ( request, response )
{
   // Pass the response to another error handler
   // accessible from all routes.
   const errorHandler = error =>
      trueErrorHandler
      (
         error, request, response,
         errorHandler, SomeRoute
      );
   
   eventEmmiter.on('error', errorHandler);
   
   // Do your route stuff here...
});

const trueErrorHandler = ( error, request, response, errorHandler, routeFunction ) =>
{
   // Handle your errors from all routes here?
   
   // Now I just need to see if routeFunction is in the error stack.
   if ( error.stack.split("\n").filter(line => line.trim().startsWith(`at ${routeFunction.name}`) ).length )
   {
      // The error matches the route.
      // Now you know where it came from.
      
      // Remove the listener
      eventEmmiter.removeListener('error', errorHandler);
   }
}

You can just repeat the pattern at every route... Or you can just manage the exceptions specifically at each route instead of using the trueErrorHandler() function.
EDIT 2: I developed this more complete example in a working snippet. It should be very useful.


// MOCKING EVERYTHING...

// There's the asynchronous function that
// maybe can throw an unhandled error.
async function delayedError ( interval = 500 )
{
  // You want to catch an unhandled error
  // thrown from here or after some crazy
  // stuff happens, but originated from
  // here anyways...
  
  // Produces an error after 0.5 seconds.
  setTimeout((... unused) => ( inexistent [ Symbol() ] () ), interval);
};

// Then there's the routes of your app in
// which the delayed/asynchronous error
// may or not happen.

async function appRoute1 ( request, response )
{
  let value;
  
  // Install the unhandled error handler.
  const error = new AsyncError( () => value === undefined );
  
  // Safely call the asynchronous dubious function...
  value = await delayedError(500);
  
  // Then safely handle any error...
  console.log('VALUE OR ERROR (Route 1):', value ?? (await error)?.message);
}

async function appRoute2 ( request, response )
{
  let value;
  
  // Install the unhandled error handler.
  const error = new AsyncError( () => value === undefined );
  
  // Safely call the asynchronous dubious function...
  value = await delayedError(1000);
  
  // Then safely handle any error...
  console.log('VALUE OR ERROR (Route 2):', value ?? (await error)?.message);
}

async function appRoute3 ( request, response )
{
  let value;
  
  // Install the unhandled error handler.
  const error = new AsyncError( () => value === undefined );
  
  // Safely call the asynchronous dubious function...
  value = await
  (
    async function noError ()
    {
      const promise = new Promise
      (
        ( resolve, reject ) =>
        {
          setTimeout(()=>resolve('no error'), 1500)
        }
      );
      
      return await promise;
    }
  )
  .call();
  
  // Then safely handle any error...
  console.log('VALUE OR ERROR (Route 3):', value ?? (await error)?.message);
}

function AsyncError ( tester )
{
  let resolver, rejector, error;
  
  const promise = new Promise
  (
    ( resolve, reject ) =>
    {
      resolver = resolve;
      rejector = reject;
    }
  );
  
  const listener = asyncError =>
  {
    error = asyncError;
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('error', listener);
  
  const interval = setInterval
  (
    () =>
    {
      if ( error || ( ( typeof tester == 'function' ) && ! tester() ) )
      {
        resolver(error);
        window.removeEventListener('error', listener);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 10
  );
  
  return promise;
}

// TESTING
console.clear();
appRoute1();
appRoute2();
appRoute3();
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }




This works, but not completely. The environment here is a node/express server. Ideally I'd send the client a 500 response or something, so it'd need to somehow have access to the response object.

@Omaro_IB Friend, this should be another question,,, But my answer is still valid. You should just place this code at the beginning of every route where you have the response object. Then inside the error handler you'll have the access to the response object as well.

@Omaro_IB I also suggest that you remove the event handler after the response is sent.

@Omaro_IB Maybe this edit can solve your problem...

"You should just place this code at the beginning of every route" - no, absolutely not. An unhandled rejection anywhere would send the error to totally unrelated responses.

While this would work, it's going to totally bork your error handling.

@Bergi As you know, the OP question asks to resolve a very specific problem which is to handle unexpected unhandled errors. This workaround does just that. It's still possible to handle these unhandled errrors with precision by adding more logic layers to the handler function... But this is already out of the scope of que question, so I didn't bother to do it. PS.: It looks like crazyness to me when someone asks something in order to achieve "that" (that wasn't included in the question) and later accepts an answer unrelated to the question that is answering a totally different question...

@Bergi It is clear that my answer is the right one for the OP question. But the accepted answer does not answer it. It does not handle the unhandled error. It just suggest that you should fix the error so it does not happen instead of handling it.

"It's still possible to handle these unhandled errrors with precision by adding more logic layers to the handler function" - no its not, since you cannot know which route call the error belongs to! "It looks like crazyness to me when someone […] later accepts an answer unrelated to the question" - or maybe you just didn't get the question.

@Bergi "How to handle unexpected errors thrown inside an async function?" is a very simple question. The accepted answer is like: "just fix the error with a patch so it won't happen.". Is like I'm asking "how to get there by car?" and someone answers "just go by plane" (the question is still unanswered). Also, if you add some logic you can know exactly what route fired the error event... Just examine the backtrace... But as I said, this is outside the scope of the question...

@KLASANGUI The only correct answer is "the location is not accessible by car". Then an answer can suggest to build a road and bridge, or use a plane instead. The answer is not "just get insurance and start driving".

@KLASANGUI "Just examine the backtrace" - it seems you are not familiar with asynchronous functions. There is none.

@Bergi You're just wrong there. There are backtraces, even in errors thrown inside async functions... Just paste & run ( async function isThisUntraced () { mock.produceError() } ).call(); in your console and see if there's backtrace or not...

@Bergi See this last edit (the last code), it looks like just a little logic can solve the problem... Like naming the route listener and passing it to the error handler to test against the error stack... And you'll know exactly from what route the error came. I know this is a very complex workaround, but it works.

@KLASANGUI Sure there's stack traces in async function. Those are irrelevant though. An actual asynchronous exception, thrown in a setTimeout callback, does not contain a stack trace back to the part where setTimeout was called. Did you even try the OP's example?

@KLASANGUI "it looks like just a little logic can solve the problem" - no it can't! Even if you can identify which route caused the problem, you cannot pinpoint the exact call. Your code just installs multiple event listeners, and in case there are concurrent requests, it will send the wrong message to multiple response objects.

@Bergi See the example I developed in the snippet. I just did.

That code is so confused it's not even discernible how it how it was meant to work. (Please post it on [coderview.SE], I could give a more complete list of problems there than in a comment). And I assure you, it doesn't work. Four simple ways to make that apparent: 1) replace the delayedError() implementation with setTimeout(() => console.log('does not throw'), interval); 2) replace the delayedError() calls with the resolveAfter2Seconds() function from the OP's code 3) throw different errors per route in delayedError or 4) change resolve('no error') to resolve(undefined).

The best option is to not use the library code - file a bug report about it and write your own 2 second delay function.
There is  horrendously horrible hack you might like to try not withstanding how awful you might think it: define the variable using the name reported in the syntax errors you know about. It may work because if it's undefined, nobody else has defined it

If you want to catch promise errors every time the delay function is used, define it as a rejected promise:
const rejectPromise = Promise.reject("resolveAfter2Seconds is broken - do not call");
rejectPromise.catch(()=>null);
global[undefined_variable_name_string] = rejectPromise;

Note you would need to provide a catch handler on calls to resolveAfter2Seconds - it won't generate an uncaught rejection if you forget.

If you want the resolveAfter2Seconds to actually work you could define the variable as undefined:
 global[undefined_variable_name_string] = undefined;



Warning This the worst kind of hack I think I've ever contemplated. I hope it does not get used..
Why might it be needed
The syntax error occurs in the timer call back function while preparing the argument to pass to resolve (which never gets called). Since timer call backs are called with a clean stack, it is not being monitored by Promise code as a Promise job in the microtask queue, and the error will never turn up in a catch handler. To be exact the promise returned   by resolveAfter2Seconds simply remains pending.

The undefined_variable appears to be only an example. I don't think the OP is asking how to work around that particular bug.

@Bergi even if the question is using a made up example, the nature of the error would always prevent it being caught in promise catch code with no remediation available using standard promise programming techniques. I recommend the answer from @klvs regarding how to deal with this in production.

Yes, I just think the first and last paragraph of your answer would have sufficed. (Or really the duplicates that explain you cannot catch such an exception)
